# Integrate socket.io into angularjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I am trying to add socket.io to my angularjs project. My reference is http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/?redirect_from_locale=zh#disqus_thread. I am trying to modify it as below:

About the socket.io server:
app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

// Hook Socket.io into Express
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Socket.io Communication

var socket = require('./scripts/socket.js');
io.sockets.on('connection', socket);

// Start server at http://127.0.0.1:3000

server.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

scripts/socket.js:

```
// Keep track of which names are used so that there are no duplicates
var userNames = (function () {
  var names = {};

  var claim = function (name) {
    if (!name || names[name]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      names[name] = true;
      return true;
    }
  };

  // find the lowest unused "guest" name and claim it
  var getGuestName = function () {
    var name,
      nextUserId = 1;

    do {
      name = 'Guest ' + nextUserId;
      nextUserId += 1;
    } while (!claim(name));

    return name;
  };

  // serialize claimed names as an array
  var get = function () {
    var res = [];
    for (user in names) {
      res.push(user);
    }

    return res;
  };

  var free = function (name) {
    if (names[name]) {
      delete names[name];
    }
  };

  return {
    claim: claim,
    free: free,
    get: get,
    getGuestName: getGuestName
  };
}());

// export function for listening to the socket
module.exports = function (socket) {
  var name = userNames.getGuestName();

  // send the new user their name and a list of users
  socket.emit('init', {
    name: name,
    users: userNames.get()
  });

  // notify other clients that a new user has joined
  socket.broadcast.emit('user:join', {
    name: name
  });

  // broadcast a user's message to other users
  socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('send:message', {
      user: name,
      text: data.message
    });
  });

  // validate a user's name change, and broadcast it on success
  socket.on('change:name', function (data, fn) {
    if (userNames.claim(data.name)) {
      var oldName = name;
      userNames.free(oldName);

      name = data.name;

      socket.broadcast.emit('change:name', {
        oldName: oldName,
        newName: name
      });

      fn(true);
    } else {
      fn(false);
    }
  });

  // clean up when a user leaves, and broadcast it to other users
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user:left', {
      name: name
    });
    userNames.free(name);
  });
};
```

These are all the files for socket.io.
After node app.js, it displays "Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode"

---

The angular part is modified from the angular seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Socket.io IM Demo App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"></head>
<body>
  <h1>Angular Socket.io IM Demo App</h1>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Messages</h3>
      <div class="overflowable">
        <p ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="{alert: message.user == 'chatroom'}">: </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Users</h3>
      <div class="overflowable">
        <p ng-repeat="user in users"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr">
      <form ng-submit="sendMessage()">
        Message:
        <input size="60" ng-model="message">
        <input type="submit" value="Send"></form>
    </div>
    <div class="clr">
      <h3>Change your name</h3>
      <p>Your current user name is </p>
      <form ng-submit="changeName()">
        <input ng-model="newName">
        <input type="submit" value="Change Name"></form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js/app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']);
```

js/services.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.value('version', '0.1')
.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect(); 
    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

js/controllers.js:

```
/* Controllers */

function AppCtrl($scope, socket) {

  // Socket listeners
  // ================
  socket.on('init', function (data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.users = data.users;
  });

  socket.on('send:message', function (message) {
    $scope.messages.push(message);
  });

  socket.on('change:name', function (data) {
    changeName(data.oldName, data.newName);
  });

  socket.on('user:join', function (data) {
    $scope.messages.push({
      user: 'chatroom',
      text: 'User ' + data.name + ' has joined.'
    });
    $scope.users.push(data.name);
  });

  // add a message to the conversation when a user disconnects or leaves the room
  socket.on('user:left', function (data) {
    $scope.messages.push({
      user: 'chatroom',
      text: 'User ' + data.name + ' has left.'
    });
    var i, user;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
      user = $scope.users[i];
      if (user === data.name) {
        $scope.users.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  // Private helpers
  // ===============

  var changeName = function (oldName, newName) {
    // rename user in list of users
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.users[i] === oldName) {
        $scope.users[i] = newName;
      }
    }

    $scope.messages.push({
      user: 'chatroom',
      text: 'User ' + oldName + ' is now known as ' + newName + '.'
    });
  }

  // Methods published to the scope
  // ==============================

  $scope.changeName = function () {
    socket.emit('change:name', {
      name: $scope.newName
    }, function (result) {
      if (!result) {
        alert('There was an error changing your name');
      } else {

        changeName($scope.name, $scope.newName);

        $scope.name = $scope.newName;
        $scope.newName = '';
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.messages = [];

  $scope.sendMessage = function () {
    socket.emit('send:message', {
      message: $scope.message
    });

    // add the message to our model locally
    $scope.messages.push({
      user: $scope.name,
      text: $scope.message
    });

    // clear message box
    $scope.message = '';
  };
}
```

---

Then I run the angularjs in localhost:8000. In the webpage it seems I can send something which caused the bower to update:

```
[Mon, 28 Jul 2014 20:10:13 GMT] "GET /app/lib/angular/angular.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (
Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.1
53 Safari/537.36"
[Mon, 28 Jul 2014 20:10:13 GMT] "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Wind
ows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 S
afari/537.36"
```

However the socket.io running on localhost:3000 receives nothing.

I guess I must have something wrong in the connection between angularjs and socket.io, such as the

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

in the index.html, or the

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

in the js/services.js.

I tried to change them to

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

or

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

or

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

or

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

but nothing works. Maybe I am on a completely wrong way.

So I copy paste my code here, hope someone can help me. Any help or suggestions will be grateful.

**UPDATE**
Now it seems the client can connect to the server, but can't load the controller correctly. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Is /scripts/socket.js your server side handler?

Comment: @NathanRomano Yes, it is.

Comment: Does /script/socket.io.js resolve to a 404?

Comment: @NathanRomano Well, I just tested it again. If I put the "<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>" in the index.html, I can access the socket.io.js via the link in the Inspect Element. If it is <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>, the link "/socket.io/socket.io.js" in Inspect Element displays an empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what's wrong with the code above after an entire day.

1.The client should connect the socket.io server by adding explicit IP, that is:

in the services.js:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
```

in the index.html:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

2.Notice that there are no path and file lib/angular/angular.js in the angular-seed folder. Need to manually create the folder and add the file.

3.The code in the quesion did not display the data correctly.

This is the code I fixed all the bugs and it can work smoothly.
https://github.com/shaosh/angular-socketio-chatroom-example